# WordPress. Custom search form query not working from custom post_type only

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress v5.5.1, I have custom post 'song'.
I have the below search form in my header for all pages:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="song" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
</form>
```

And the search results are shown in `search.php`.

The search form works in all pages except the custom post_type page `www.example.com/song/song-1`, search query goes to 404 page not found.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29857/can-not-search-my-custom-post-type hope this will help you to solve your problem

Comment: No. My issue is the search form with `<input type="hidden" value="song" name="post_type" id="post_type" />` works across the site; it does not work only in custom post_type `song` single pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that upon adding `get` and `action` to the `form` tag as below, it solves the issue:

```
<form class="search-form" method="get" action="<?php echo bloginfo('url') ?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="song" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
</form>
```